# Render MVC form using reflection and Razor Tag Helper .Net 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, .net-core, tag-helpers

I want to create complicate form which will create structure of wizard, partial steps form, validation and submit. This structure have to use model attributes annotations to create one structure object over the model. So after reflection I have model and one other class with structure description. All properties within are strings with Fields which I have to pass on 'asp-for' tag helper. So part of the code is:

```
@foreach(var field in @group.Fields) {
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
     <div class="form-group md-form md-outline">
        <label asp-for="@field.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="@field.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@field.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
     </div>
  </div>  
}
```

This is nor working because tag helper expect expression and generate wrong values which are not expected from me. The value in @field.Name is 'PostAddress.Street1'. If I replace all of "@field.Name" with "PostAddress.Street1" everything work properly how I expected.
[image: Fields render]

## It looks small issue but I'm trying many things and reading some theads in forums but didn't find the answer. What I tried:

1. Experiment 1

Tried to inherit InputTagHelper class from dotnet library and override property For but without success. It changed ModelExpression but no changes in interface. May be base class have some logic to skip this changed object or is not correct generated:

```
[HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public new ModelExpression For
    {
        get
        {
            return base.For;
        }
        set
        {
            ModelExpression me = value;
            if (value.Model != null)
            {
                var viewData = this.ViewContext.ViewData as ViewDataDictionary<AbnServiceModel>;

                me = ModelExpressionProvider.CreateModelExpression<AbnServiceModel, string>(viewData, model => model.PostAddress.Street1);
            }
            base.For = me;
        }
    }
```

=================================================
 2. Experiment 2

## Try to get original implementation from .NET Core code and made some modification in code to fix the issue. But the code and dependencies with internal libraries were very complicated and I reject this idea.

3. Expiriment 3
   Using HTML helpers

```html
@Html.Label(@field.Name, "", new{ @class="control-label" })
@Html.Editor(@field.Name,  new { htmlAttributes = new{ @class="form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessage(@field.Name,"",new { htmlAttributes = new{ @class="text-danger" } })
```

It render components correct into the browser but client side validation using jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js is not working. Not sure why.

4. Expiriment 4 
   Using HTML helpers:

```html
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.PostAddress.Street1, new{ @class="control-label" })
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.PostAddress.Street1,  new { htmlAttributes = new{ @class="form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.PostAddress.Street1,"",new { htmlAttributes = new{ @class="text-danger" } })
```

The validation is working but class weren't applied well, may be my mistake. But other problem here is that I'm not using expression which is string which can get from model object. Also It doesn't catch all logic which is included in asp-for tag helper.

5. Experiment 5
   Tried to create my own tag helper and using generator to create the content html. But this means that I have to implement all logic like helper in dotnet core to have all functionality which is same like Expiriment 2

So I didn't find good solution of this "simple" problem and lost some days to investigate and doing some code to resolve it. I'm surprised that no way to pass string variable with property name and it wouldn't work.

Can someone help me to fix this problem with real example? I didn't find the answer in all posts. I want to have all logic from asp-for tag helper but use variable to pass the expression. It cab be and tricky, just want to have some resolution to continue with my project.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue.
Created one helper method:

```
public static class CommonHelperMethods
    {
        public static ModelExplorer GetModelExplorer(this ModelExplorer container, string field, IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider = null)
        {
            ModelExplorer result = container;
            var fields = field.Split(".").ToList();

            var match = Regex.Match(fields[0], @"(.+)\[(\d)+\]");
            if (!match.Success)
            {
                fields.ForEach(x =>
                {
                    result = result?.GetExplorerForProperty(x) ?? result;
                });
            }
            else
            { //List have to create own Property browser
                string proName = match.Groups[1].Value;
                int idx = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);
                var model = ((IList)result?.GetExplorerForProperty(proName).Model)[idx];
                var targetProperty = model.GetType().GetProperty(fields[1]);
                var targetValueModel = targetProperty.GetValue(model);


                var elementMetadata = modelMetadataProvider.GetMetadataForProperty(model.GetType(), fields[1]);
                return new ModelExplorer(modelMetadataProvider, container, elementMetadata, targetValueModel);
            }    
            return result;
        }
    }
```

And just override the tag helper class with this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
namespace GetTaxSolutions.Web.Infrastructure.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = ForAttributeName, TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
    public class InputTextGtTaxHelper : InputTagHelper
    {
        private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";
        [HtmlAttributeName("not-exp")]
        public bool NotExpression { get; set; } = false;

        [HtmlAttributeName(ForAttributeName)]
        public new ModelExpression For
        {
            get
            {
                return base.For;
            }
            set
            {
                ModelExpression me = value;
                if (NotExpression)
                {
                    var modelExplorertmp = value.ModelExplorer.Container.GetModelExplorer(value.Model.ToString(), ModelMetadataProvider);
                    var modelExplorer = new ModelExplorer(ModelMetadataProvider, value.ModelExplorer.Container, modelExplorertmp.Metadata, modelExplorertmp.Model);
                    me = new ModelExpression(value.Model.ToString(), modelExplorer);
                }
                base.For = me;
            }
        }

        public IModelExpressionProvider ModelExpressionProvider { get; }
        public IModelMetadataProvider ModelMetadataProvider { get; }
        public IActionContextAccessor Accessor { get; }

        public InputTextGtTaxHelper(
            IHtmlGenerator generator,
            IModelExpressionProvider modelExpressionProvider,
            IModelMetadataProvider modelMetaDataProvider) : base(generator)
        {
            ModelExpressionProvider = modelExpressionProvider;
            ModelMetadataProvider = modelMetaDataProvider;
        }
    }
}
```

Also should skip original class in tag helper registration:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.InputTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.LabelTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ValidationMessageTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.SelectTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper GetTaxSolutions.Web.Infrastructure.TagHelpers.*, GetTaxSolutions.Web
```

And when use model in expression just have to pass attribute 'no-exp' on input elements. Otherwise will work like original tag helper.

```
<input not-exp="true" asp-for="@field.Name" class="form-control" />
```

Also you have to do same with label, select and other used tag helpers which you want to support this way of model passing.